# How to implement custom pull-to-refresh indicator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I started out using ReactNative's [`RefreshControl`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html), which worked out great at first. Now I want something more custom.

I'd like to animate an object based on the negative/overscroll scroll value, effectively what the built in `RefreshControl` does.

I've tried listening the the `onScroll` event. But it doesn't seem to fire for negative/overscroll values. I've also tried using [GestureResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#content), but they seem to be getting terminated.

UPDATE:

I found setting `scrollEventThrottle={16}` on the `ScrollView` gives me negative/overscroll 'onScroll' events in iOS, but doesn't seem to do anything for Android.